# SAS Format DATE9. to DDMMYYd10. in select statement

Tags: date, sas, format

How can I format a DATE9. date to DDMMYYd10. in my select statement?

```
PROC SQL;
 CREATE TABLE TEST AS
 SELECT BIRTH_DT
 FROM CUSTOMER
QUIT;
```

I tried:

```
PROC SQL;
 CREATE TABLE TEST AS
 SELECT BIRTH_DT FORMAT=DDMMYYd10.
 FROM CUSTOMER
QUIT;
```

Also tried:

```
PROC SQL;
 CREATE TABLE TEST AS
 SELECT DATEPART(BIRTH_DT) FORMAT=DDMMYYd10. AS BIRTH_DT
 FROM CUSTOMER
QUIT;
```

But this raises an error.

Current output is 28MAY1960 and I need 28-05-1960

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting an error because you are missing a semi-colon `;` after the `from` statement. Also the `datepart` function is not needed.

```
data have;
  dt_birth = '28MAY1960'd;
  format dt_birth date9.;
run;

proc sql;
    create table want as
    select dt_birth format=ddmmyyd10.
    from have;
quit;
```

```
28-05-1960
```

Comment: This is a good example of why I always place the ending semi-colon for a multiple line statement on a new line.  If you leave it at the end of the last line it is too hard to see when scanning the code to confirm that all of the statements end with a semi-colon.